# Storing get call data on same function

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cache

I basically have a folder view structure, that each time I call grabs the value of the selected field and gets that specific folder data. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this by caching or something like that. So for example if I was to request that same folder it would be stored in memory, instead of having to make another get request.

```
var getFolder = function() {

    if ($('.list-group-item:hover').css('margin-left') === '0px') {
        $('.fold').remove();
    }

    var promises = [];

    $('.list-group-item').css("background-color", ""); // clear last selected

    $.get("/folder", {
        folder: $('.list-group-item:hover').attr('title') //.clone().children().text()
    }, function(data) {
        var folders = data.CommonPrefixes; // folders
        var jsonData = data.Contents; //json data

        var selected = $('.list-group-item:hover').css("background-color", "rgb(0, 196, 255)"); // new selected color



        var parFolder = parseInt($('.list-group-item:hover').css('margin-left'), 10);
        var add = parFolder + 15;
        var subFolder = add.toString() + 'px';

        if (folders.length > 0) {

            for (var k = 0; k < folders.length; k++) {

                var value = folders[k].Prefix;
                var displayVal = value.split('/').slice(-2).join("");


                var book = "<li class='fold list-group-item' onclick='getFolder()' title='" + value + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-book'></span>" + displayVal + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign' onclick='deleteFldr()'></span>" + "</li>"

                $(book).insertAfter(".list-group-item:hover").css('margin-left', subFolder);

            }
        }

        if (jsonData.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

                var req = $.get('/fldrContents', {
                    contents: jsonData[i].Key
                }, function(data) {
                    //var b = JSON.parse(data.body);
                });

                promises.push(req);

            }
        }

        $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(d) {

            if ($('.dynamic')) {
                $('.dynamic').remove();
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {

                var posTop;
                var posLeft;

                var z = JSON.parse(promises[i].responseText);
                console.log(z)

                var fileURL = z.path;

                var lastChar = fileURL.charAt(fileURL.length - 1);
                if (lastChar === '/') {
                    continue;
                }
                $('.description').css('display', 'none')

                var fileBody = JSON.parse(z.body);
                var website = fileBody.website;
                var title = fileBody.title;
                var description = fileBody.description;
                var created = fileBody.created;
                var canvasData = fileBody.canvas;

                // console.log(canvasData)

                if (fileBody.hasOwnProperty('description')) {

                    $('.description').css('display', 'block')
                }



                if (fileBody.hasOwnProperty('position')) {

                    var posTop = fileBody.position.top;
                    var posLeft = fileBody.position.left;

                    $('dynamic').css({
                        'top': posTop,
                        'left': posLeft
                    });



                    $(".static").append('<div class="dynamic col-md-6" style="top:' + posTop + 'px;left:' + posLeft + 'px">' +
                        '<div class="panel">' +
                        '<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>' +
                        '<div class="panel-body">' +
                        '<a href="' + website + '" target="_blank" class="title" title="Go to ' + website + '">' + title + '</a>' +
                        '<span class="website-edit"></span>' +
                        '<div class="description">' + description + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="panel-footer">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" title="' + fileURL + '"></span>' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" title="' + created + '"></span>' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit this bookmark" onclick="edit()"></span>' +
                        '<span class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" title="Delete this bookmark" onclick="deleteBookmark()"></span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>');
                }

                if (!fileBody.hasOwnProperty('position')) {
                    $(".static").append('<div class="dynamic col-md-6">' +
                        '<div class="panel">' +
                        '<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>' +
                        '<div class="panel-body">' +
                        '<a href="' + website + '" target="_blank" class="title" title="Go to ' + website + '">' + title + '</a>' +
                        '<span class="website-edit"></span>' +
                        '<div class="description">' + description + '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="panel-footer">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark" title="' + fileURL + '"></span>' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" title="' + created + '"></span>' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit this bookmark" onclick="edit()"></span>' +
                        '<span class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" title="Delete this bookmark" onclick="deleteBookmark()"></span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>')

                }

                if (fileBody.hasOwnProperty('canvas')) {

                    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvasData = new Image();
                    canvasData.src = promises[i];



                }



                $('.dynamic').draggable({
                    handle: "div",
                    stop: function(event, ui) {

                        var changedFile = $(this).children('.panel').children('.panel-footer').children('.glyphicon-bookmark').attr('title');

                        var pos = ui.position
                        var title = $(this).children('.panel').children('.panel-body').children('a.title').text();
                        var description = $(this).children('.panel').children('.panel-body').children('.description').text();
                        var website = $(this).children('.panel').children('.panel-body').children('a.title').attr('href');
                        var created = $(this).children('.panel').children('.panel-footer').children('.glyphicon-time').attr('title');
                        var canvas = $(this).children('.panel').children('#canvas') // fix this
                        var canvasData = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");

                        console.log(created + ' ' + title + ' ' + description + ' ' + canvasData)

                        $.post('/cssPosition', {
                            website: website,
                            title: title,
                            description: description,
                            position: pos,
                            folder: changedFile,
                            created: created,
                            canvas: canvasData
                        }, function() {

                        });
                        //location.reload();

                    }
                });



            }


        });


    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery automatically caches stuff if you set `cache: true` in [the ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). No need to roll your own

Comment: i saw that before, but i was wondering if even before the get call you could store it, because jquery caches it but its still making another request

Comment: First, check that the request actually goes anywhere. jQuery's `cache: true` basically allows the browser to use _its_ cache. A request is still _created_ (and shows up in the dev tools), but it may never leave your computer if the browser has a cache - and your server is saying that it's ok to cache responses. Again, the console/network log in the dev tools will tell you what the request did. You can still make your own cache if you need to, but that's a question for, say, StackOverflow. This site is for reviewing existing code, so we can't review code you haven't written.

Answer (score 3):

```
var selected = $('.list-group-item:hover').css("background-color", "rgb(0, 196, 255)");
```

`rgb(0, 196, 255` tells me nothing, as I am not a computer and I can't visualize a color with just those numbers in my head.

Create a variable called with the name of the equivalent color in all caps, and set it to that `rgb` string.

For example, if you were changing the background to red, you would put:

```
var REDISH_ORANGE = "rgb(255, 68, 0)";

var selected = $('.list-group-item:hover').css("background-color", REDISH_ORANGE);
```

---

```
var parFolder = parseInt($('.list-group-item:hover').css('margin-left'), 10);
var add = parFolder + 15;
var subFolder = add.toString() + 'px';
```

This is a waste of memory; you are only using `parFolder` and `add` a single time, and that single time is to help create the variable right beneath it.

Just chain these together and stick them in `subFolder`:

```
var subFolder = (parseInt($('.list-group-item:hover').css('margin-left', 10) + 15).toString() + 'px';
```

Yes, you are only using `subFolder` once, but the name "subFolder" is describing what the value is. Names like "parFolder" (which I assume is short for "Parsed int folder", or something like that) and "add" sound like "filler words" and mean nothing to the variable or context.

---

You use

```
$('.list-group-item:hover')
```

quite a lot. Stick this into a variable so it is easier to access.

---

[In your function, you should `"use strict";`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it?rq=1).

---

This code was a little difficult to review without seeing the webpage, and without seeing the file structure/tree.

If you could add these to your post, I could edit my answer to add more improvements.

Comment: thanks for the review! I'm basically replicating a folder type structure for the UI and this particular function is getting all the contents of the folder and appending it to the view.